# Guardar por medio de VBA

Tags: excel, vba, exportar, guardar, carga

Tengo este código para guardar un documento por medio de VBA, pero estoy teniendo problema ya que se está guardando en otra carpeta. Tengo entendido que la carpeta donde se guarda es la predeterminada. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar a que se guarde en la carpeta que requiero sin tener que cambiar la carpeta predeterminada de Excel?

```
Sub SAVE()
'Declaraci{on de variables
Dim num, mes, nom, direc, a, b, pass, anio As String

'Guardamos
    With ActiveWorkbook
        Sheets("IMPRESIÓN").Select
        num = InputBox("Indique el número consecutivo del archivo", "Consecutivo")
        mes = Cells(6, 2)
            If mes = "Seleccione un mes" Then
                mes = InputBox("Especifique el mes", "Mes")
            End If
        anio = Cells(6, 4)
        If anio = "" Then
                anio = InputBox("Especifique el año", "Año")
            End If
        nom = InputBox("Escriba el nombre del cliente", "Nombre")
        direc = "Z:\Transferencia2\ADATA_USB_Flash_Drive-1\EMPRESA CORP AUT JJ 2023\CARPETA 2023\REMISION\" & mes & "\"
        a = num & " " & nom & ".xlsx"
        b = MsgBox("El documento se gusrdadará en esta dirección " & direc & a & " , ¿es correcto?", vbOKCancel, "Dirección")
        If b = vbOK Then
            'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .SaveAs Filename:=Environ(direc) & a, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            '.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Lo está guardando en la dirección que tienes puesto en `direc`. Cambia ese valor y listo.